# Using dictionaries and CSV files in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

When I ask if a certain movie in the nominees file is the same as the one my user inputted, my code fails:

```
#!python
import csv

with open('nominees.csv', newline='') as f:
  winningtitle=input("Winning title: ")
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):  
     if line['title']==winningtitle:
      print('Congratulations:', line['director(s)'])
```

However, when I ask if the length of the movie title is the same length as the user input, it works:

```
#!python
import csv

with open('nominees.csv', newline='') as f:
  winningtitle=input("Winning title: ")
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):  
     if len(line['title'])==len(winningtitle):
      print('Congratulations:', line['director(s)'])
```

Obviously, Code #2 is cheating. What is wrong with Code #1?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a tip, you should highlight your code sections and hit the {} button for code formatting. Right now it's hard to read.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Any error message?

Comment: Did you try to print and see what is compared to what? Also, when doing case-insensitive comparisons it's common to call to `str.lower()`

Comment: I'd start by trying a `.strip()` and `.lower()` on both `winningtitle` and `line[title]` before comparing them -- and if that's now enough normalize deeper, e.g removing punctuation and collapsing all remaining whitespace sequences to a single `' '`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! It turns out that there was nothing wrong with my code. The CSV file that I was inputting data from had a UTF-8 apostrophe instead of a regular apostrophe, and so when I typed in Schindler's List it didn't register as the same thing. Hard to catch! Thanks!